# Call a different controller but save the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a C# MVC web application.
I have 2 controllers. Each one has methods that returns  HttpResponseMessage with this line:

```
  return Request.CreateResponse(<StatusCode>, <value>);
```

I need that method2 in controller2 will call method1 in controller1, get its response and use it to create its own response. So I create controller1 in method2 of controller2, and than call its method1 -

```
 // Controler 1
 [InitializeSimpleMembership]
 public class ItemsController : ApiController, IDisposable
 {
      Service1 m_s1;
      Service2 m_s2;
      Service3 m_s3;
      Service4 m_s4;
     // Controler 1 constructor
        public ItemsController (Service1 s1, Service2 s2, Service3 s3, Service4 s4)
        {
           m_s1 = s1;
           m_s2 = s2;
           m_s3 = s3; 
           m_s4 = s4;
        }
        // Controler 1 Method1
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Method1(IEnumerable<Item> items)
        {
            List<Item> items2 = new  List<Item>();
            // ...
           if (...) 
           {
              return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items2);
           }
           else  
           {
              return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, errorList);
           }
        }   
 }

 // Controler 2
 [InitializeSimpleMembership]
 public class CarsController : ApiController, IDisposable
 {
      Service1 m_s1;
      Service4 m_s4;
      Service5 m_s5;

       // Controler 2 Constructor
        public CarsController(Service1 s1, Service4 s4, Service5 s5)
        {
           m_s1 = s1;
           m_s4 = s4;
           m_s5 = s5; 
        }

       // Controler 2 method2 
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Method2(Car car)
        {
            // ...
            Service2 s2 = new Service2();
            Service3 s3 = new Service3();
            ItemsController itemsController = new ItemsController (m_s1, s2, s3, m_s4);
            HttpResponseMessage response = itemsController.Method1(items);
            List<Item> items2;
            response.TryGetContentValue<List<Item>>(out items2);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items2);
        }   
 }
```

The problem is that when I create controller1 (ItemsController) like that - it has no "Request" (it is null).
So I tried to send the request like that -

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Method1_Shell(IEnumerable<Item> items, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (Request == null)
        {
            Request = request;
        }
        return Method1(items);
    }
```

But I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> I need that method2 in controller2 will call method1 in controller1, get its response and use it to create its own response. So I create controller1 in method2 of controller2, and than call its method1

I believe that it is the matter of concerns which are split in your application incorrectly. In this case I would recommend you to create some service which would do the work which you do in `ItemsController` and share it between two controllers.

With shared service approach you are getting at least following benefits:

1. You can get rid from tight coupling and unneeded complex logic with instantiation of other controller and calling its method.
2. Your other controller would look simpler without second 
   `HttpRequestMessage` parameter.

Comment: yes, but i'll take a lot of time of a factoring work and I can't do it right now, only in the future. I need to handle the existing situation. (I'm not my boss :) )

Comment: @TamarG I'm not familiar with your situation well enough, however by looking at code samples you have presented I can say the code in `CarsController` is very coupled to `ItemsController`. Therefore in future it would be difficult to make further changes, it could be convincing for your boss :)

Comment: It's not my real code, of course, I changed the code and the names to be as general as I could, and copied here only what I needed for the example. In my code - every controller has many methods and a long code in each method... :)

Comment: @TamarG I would say that each controller method having a lot of code is the second ring that you should change it. Just try to search in the internet by key phrases like 'thin controller' or 'put controllers on diet' and you will know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you use a request uri and send a http request in controller2 to controller1. Get the response and edit.